# Passing value from excel file to file name - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My code below. I have a script which if we have files for example:

```
"TABNAME_C.txt", "TABNAME_D.txt"
```

First of them has a 2000 records, and second has a 900 records. In output I get

```
TABNAME_C_1.txt with 1000 records, 
TABNAME_C_2.txt with other 1000 records, 
TABNAME_D_1.txt with 900 records
```

I have a excel file where I have

```
TABNAME, SCHEMA, QUERY
```

After merge I have in TABNAME_C_1.txt with QUERY from excel and it's good. But I have a problem because I would like a format filename if TABNAME1 = TABNAME

```
"SCHEMA_TABNAME_C_1.txt",
"SCHEMA_TABNAME_C_2.txt",
"SCHEMA_TABNAME_D_1.txt"
```

```
import re
import os
import shutil
import pandas as pd

lines_per_file = 1000
smallfile = None

root_path = 'D:/xlsx/WWW/'

if os.path.exists(root_path):
    files = []
    for name in os.listdir(root_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root_path, name)):
            files.append(os.path.join(root_path, name))
    # print(files) #list all files in directory

    for ii in files:
        if ii.endswith(".txt"):  # only txt files
            with open(ii, 'r') as bigfile:
                b = os.path.abspath(ii)
                print('name2', b)
                name1 = str(os.path.basename(ii).split(".")[0])
                name2 = str(name1 + '_{}.txt')
                #
                print('name1', name1)
                for lineno, line in enumerate(bigfile):
                    if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
                        if smallfile:
                            smallfile.close()
                        small_filename = name2.format(lineno // lines_per_file + 1)
                        smallfile = open(os.path.join(root_path, small_filename), "w")
                    smallfile.write(line)
                if smallfile:
                    smallfile.close()

if os.path.exists(root_path):
    files = []
    for name in os.listdir(root_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root_path, name)):
            files.append(os.path.join(root_path, name))
    print('files', files)  # list all files in directory

    # removing empty newlines
    for bb in files:
        if bb.endswith(".txt"):  # only txt files
            with open(bb, 'r') as f:
                content = f.read()
                f.close()
                content1 = content.split("\n")
                s = "\n".join(content1[:-1])
                f = open(bb, "w+")
                for i in range(len(s)):
                    f.write(s[i])
                f.close()

            with open(bb, 'r') as p:
                content = p.read()
                p.close()
                file = []
                name1 = str(os.path.basename(bb).rsplit('_', 1)[0])
                print("NAME1", name1)
                file.append(name1)
                dd = pd.DataFrame(file, columns=['TABNAME1'])
                print(dd)
                df = pd.read_excel('D:/xlsx/FILE.xlsx')
                print(df)
                c = pd.merge(dd, df, how='inner', left_on='TABNAME1', right_on='TABNAME')
                g = c.loc[:, "SCHEMA"]
```

Comment: Unrelated but please use actual naming for your variables. Single-letter naming makes your code unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

To change the file name format based on the value of TABNAME, you can modify the following line:

```
name2 = str(name1 + '_{}.txt')
```

to:

```
if name1.startswith('TABNAME'):
    name2 = str(c.iloc[0]['SCHEMA'] + '_' + name1 + '_{}.txt')
else:
    name2 = str(name1 + '_{}.txt')
```

This checks if the file name starts with "TABNAME" and if so, it replaces "TABNAME" with the corresponding value of SCHEMA from the merged data. Otherwise, it keeps the original format.

Here's the modified code:

```
import re
import os
import shutil
import pandas as pd

lines_per_file = 1000
smallfile = None

root_path = 'D:/xlsx/WWW/'

if os.path.exists(root_path):
    files = []
    for name in os.listdir(root_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root_path, name)):
            files.append(os.path.join(root_path, name))
    # print(files) #list all files in directory

    for ii in files:
        if ii.endswith(".txt"):  # only txt files
            with open(ii, 'r') as bigfile:
                b = os.path.abspath(ii)
                print('name2', b)
                name1 = str(os.path.basename(ii).split(".")[0])
                if name1.startswith('TABNAME'):
                    dd = pd.DataFrame([name1], columns=['TABNAME1'])
                    df = pd.read_excel('D:/xlsx/FILE.xlsx')
                    c = pd.merge(dd, df, how='inner', left_on='TABNAME1', right_on='TABNAME')
                    name2 = str(c.iloc[0]['SCHEMA'] + '_' + name1 + '_{}.txt')
                else:
                    name2 = str(name1 + '_{}.txt')
                #
                print('name1', name1)
                for lineno, line in enumerate(bigfile):
                    if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
                        if smallfile:
                            smallfile.close()
                        small_filename = name2.format(lineno // lines_per_file + 1)
                        smallfile = open(os.path.join(root_path, small_filename), "w")
                    smallfile.write(line)
                if smallfile:
                    smallfile.close()

if os.path.exists(root_path):
    files = []
    for name in os.listdir(root_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root_path, name)):
            files.append(os.path.join(root_path, name))
    print('files', files)  # list all files in directory

    # removing empty newlines
    for bb in files:
        if bb.endswith(".txt"):  # only txt files
            with open(bb, 'r') as f:
                content = f.read()
                f.close()
                content1 = content.split("\n")
                s = "\n".join(content1[:-1])
                f = open(bb, "w+")
                for i in range(len(s)):
                    f.write(s[i])
                f.close()

            with open(bb, 'r') as p:
                content = p.read()
                p.close()
                file = []
                name1 = str(os.path.basename(bb).rsplit('_', 1)[0])
                print("NAME1", name1)
                file.append(name1)
                dd = pd.DataFrame(file, columns=['TABNAME1'])
                print(dd)
                df = pd.read_excel('D:/xlsx/FILE.xlsx')
                print(df)
                c = pd.merge(dd, df, how='inner', left_on='TABNAME1', right_on='TABNAME')
                g = c.loc[:, "SCHEMA"]
```

Comment: What if I have files such as TABNAME_C_1.txt, POLICY_1.txt, property_1.txt

Comment: you can use the same formatting tools, just extending the logic